# Pycharm Bookmarks. Meaning of Number 7 on pycharm IDE

Tags: pycharm

I don't know how to look for this "issue".

On pycharm a number `7` has appear on a file.

[image: pycharm wierd number]

It happens that appears next to a line does generates an error.

I can't interactuate with it or eliminate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a bookmark. You have accidently placed that with CTRL-SHIFT-7. You can remove that using the same shortcut. To jump to that bookmark use CTRL-7.